# Makes using a URI as predicate them to a property?

Tags: properties, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

I have only the following Turtle statement:

```
x isAuthorOf y
```

If I have only this statement where isAuthorOf is used as a predicate, means this that I can conclude that isAuthorOf is also a Property without instanciation (isAuthorOf rdf:type rdfs:Property)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an IRI used ad a property implies it is a property. However, without declaration you won't know if it's a datatype or an object property.